# Prove that a function is not differentiable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $A = \{(x, y) | x = y , x > 0 \}, A \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $, let

$$\phi(x, y) = 
    \begin{cases}  
    x^{2/3}  &if \ x \in A,\\
    0  &if \ x \notin A.  \end{cases} $$

how to proove that $\phi$ is not is  differentiable at the origin ?

Comment: Does
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{h^{2/3}}{h}$$
exist?

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\phi((x,y)+t(h_1,h_2)) - \phi(x,y)}{t}$$ is not a linear function of $h=(h_1,h_2)$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Because $\phi(0,0) =0$, you have to compute $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\phi(th_1,th_2)}{t}.$$ But remark that this limit isn't even finite if $h_1=h_2$ and $h_1 >0.$

Comment: this might sound stupid, but how does the non-existence of a directional  derivative, connect with the differentiability of a function ?

Comment: A function $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if there is a linear map $T$ such that $f(x) = f(x_0)+T(x-x_0) + o(|x-x_0|)$ when $x \to x_0$. If it is the case we have that $T(h)$ is the directional derivative. Hence if the directional derivative doesn't exist, the function can't be differentiable.

Comment: could you please clarify why $T(h)$ is the directional derivative ? P.S. I do understand that $x-x_0 = h$

Comment: maybe I am starting to understand, it has something to do with the fact that  $T^{T}$ is the gradient of the function ?